# MVC Bundling: How to use parents website bundled resources in child webapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, bundling-and-minification

I have a website in IIS, under the website there are  couples of web applications (website and web applications all are mvc web application).

The website uses ASP.NET MVC bundling -

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Styles", "*.css", true));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/js")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/Scripts", "*.js", true));
}
```

In website _Layout.cshtml -

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Script.Render("~/Content/js")
```

When website is browsed (e.g. mywebsite.com), I can see querystring attached to those references.

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=asdsf$dfsdfdslkko" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Content/js?v=jjkase$rads@asdasd"></script>
```

And for my child web application under that website in IIS, if I have to use same bundled resources, I can do (in webapp layout page) -

```
@Styles.Render("/Content/css")
@Script.Reder("/Content/js")
```

When webapp is browsed (e.g. mywebsite.com/mywebapp), I can access those resource from parent website but I couldnot get those querystrings in style and script references.

```
<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Content/js></scripts>
```

The only difference is I must use starting `/` for webapp which is the cause for not generating querystring. It's a weird behavior. I need querystring while browsing webapp too (to avoid cache). If I used `/` instead of `~` in my parent website also, querystring gets dissapeared (DISGUSTING).

Is there anyway to retain querystring even `/` is used for referencing bundles? Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid cache on a bundled resource, just why?

Comment: querystring gets changed only when underlying resource is modified, if it is not modified, we can get them from browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

First off, bundling is project-centric. There's no way to share bundles in one application with another, child or not. What you're doing here is essentially taking advantage of the fact that the bundling framework actually caches the created bundles to a real file, which then allows you to reference it in the other project as you would any other random static JavaScript/CSS file. However, with this approach, you're going to lose some of the niceties of using a bundle directly, such as the automatic appending of that cache-busting query string.

Technically, you can append your own query string. There's nothing special about it, really; it's just a random string that tricks the user's browser into thinking it's a different resource, and thus making it fetch it again. For example:

```
<script src="/Content/js?foo123></scripts>
```

However, you're going to be responsible for updating the query string whenever you change any of the scripts in that bundle. Using the actual bundle directly, it's smart enough to know something has changed and append a different query string, but if you're just statically linking, then there's no automated process to do that for you.

Comment: We can create multiple applications inside root website in `IIS`, and I am able to reference resources from root to other applications but couldn't get the benefit of mvc bundling.